# Nextjs custom server Express HTML/CSS not showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

Good day, I'm a beginner website developer, for 5 days now I cannot find a solution in which I cannot render the HTML/CSS of my next login page. It's only rendering the data from the server. The app uses custom server using Express.

```
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next';

type Events = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  isbn: number
}
interface IEvents {
  events: Events[];
}

const Login: NextPage<IEvents> = (events) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>hi events</h2>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(events)}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<IEvents> = async (ctx) => {
 const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login')
 const events: Events[] = await data.json()

  return {
    props: {events}, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
}

export default Login
```

This is the server.js file, when I go to the "/login" page the component is not showing up, instead the json data from the server without the component page is showing.

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  const events = {
    id: 123,
    name: "Pepe",
    isbn: 14696897
  }
  server.get( "/login", (req,res) => {
    res.json(events)
  })
  server.all("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });

}).catch( ex => { //catch any exceptions
  console.error(ex.stack);  //display stack for error
  process.exit(1)   //kill the process with exit code of one so that the server crashes and burns
})
```

This is the root component of the app.

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import { FC } from 'react';
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { store } from "../store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Layout } from "../components/layout/Layout";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const MyApp: FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Layout {...pageProps}> 
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Does this work as intended:`const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login')`. How is the file this variable is defined in called? Also *login*? Is it directly in the page directory? There could be some kind of naming conflict, is my guess.

Comment: the only problem is that, the login component is not rendering but the json data from express is the only one showing in the browser page.

Comment: the component is rendering perfectly without the data coming from the express. But once express is being used together, with client side, the client side is failing.

Comment: That's because you're telling the Next.js server to return the JSON data in the custom server for the `/login` route. Adding `server.get( "/login", (req,res) => {})` will take precedence and actually overwrite what you have in `/pages/login`. I would recommend you use an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) instead, so you don't even need the custom server.